# How to figure out if a location is within a square (lat,lon) PHP

Tags: php, html, math, geolocation

How can you figure out if this:

```
$Now = array(
'lat' => '59.565423',
'long' => '7.347268'
);
```

is inside this:

```
$x = array(
'x1' => '59.570281',  // point 1, north west - lat
'y1' => '7.341667',   // ^^^^^^ - lon
'x2' => '59.570281',  // point 2, north east - lat
'y2' => '7.351087',   // ^^^^^^ - lon
'x3' => '59.568195',  // point 3, south east - lat
'y3' => '7.351087',   // ^^^^^^ - lon
'x4' => '59.568195',  // point 4, south west - lat
'y4' => '7.341667'    // ^^^^^^ - lon
 );
```

Supposed to return 1 if inside or 0 if outside.

Comment: You need to be more precise - do you want to output an array which contains the coordinates within a given range? It is unlikely they will match exactly. Next question - what is x? The latitude or the longitude? And (likewise) what is y?

Comment: @Matt It was a question i answered myself (as ive heard other people asking about it) ive given the answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice - the question (without your answer) appeared in the triage view of the stack overflow review tool, so I did not read the answer there. In this case, please disregard my request. Btw. I gave you a +1 for the answer. :-)

Comment: i would recommend you change the structure of your array that's flaming confusing whats wrong with an array or object inside an array?

`$x = array('nw' => array(59.570281, 7.341667)...)`

Comment: @Martin Baker, see me comment above. Once you have this question that array makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

- first you need to check if longitude is within your |---| area so:

  `if($Now['long'] > $x['y1'] && $Now['long'] < $x['y2'])`

  - then you need to check if the latitude is within the parameters:

  `if($Now['lat'] < $x['x1'] && $Now['lat'] > $x['x4'])`

Whole function:

```
function InsideOrNot($Now, $x){
    //If 0 is within |----| (|--0--|)
    if($Now['long'] > $x['y1'] && $Now['long'] < $x['y2']){

        //if 0 is within ___
        //                |
        //               ___   
        if($Now['lat'] < $x['x1'] && $Now['lat'] > $x['x4']){
            return 1;
        }

        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Now: `echo InsideOrNot($Now, $x);`